# AngularJS - compare two array and disable on same case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two table: "Available subject" and "Added subject" that filled (ng-repeat) by two list of object. I need to make three things from them:

1 - When user press the plus sign, a row with the same content appear on "Added subject"

2 - When user press the remove sign, the row disappear

3 - Any plus sign button will be disabled if there are a same row in "Added subject"

I've done the first and second task so far but I got no solution for the last one
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function in your controller to toggle a `added` subject state.

Here is a sample snippet to achieve this

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.subjects = [{
                name: "XXX",
                id: "123",
                added: false
            },
            {
                name: "YYY",
                id: "456",
                added: true
            },
            {
                name: "ZZZ",
                id: "789",
                added: false
            },
        ];

        $scope.addRemoveSubject = function(subject) {
            subject.added = !subject.added;
        };

    }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <h3>Available subjects</h3>
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="subject in subjects">
      <strong>{{subject.name}}</strong> {{subject.id}} <button ng-click="addRemoveSubject(subject)" ng-disabled="subject.added">Add</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Added Subjects</h3>
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="subject in subjects | filter:{added:true}">
      <strong>{{subject.name}}</strong> {{subject.id}} <button ng-click="addRemoveSubject(subject)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great answer! Just remove `<script src="script.js"></script>` from the snippet to get rid of the js error

Comment: Good point ! I used plunker to write my example and forgot to remove it once in embedded snippet ;)